# My ROG Asus computer do not have wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, asus

I did network reset and wifi is gone from Network & Internet Settings

[image]

However, the wifi is doing fine and show up Network Connections.

[image]

So wifi working. I already reinstall the wifi. Yet that wifi doesn't show up

If I put another wifi dongle then another wifi connection will show up. However, I cannot connect to wifi because wifi is not available.

All this happened because I did "Network Reset" for another problems that has been fixed.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Did you restart?

Comment: Already several times. Already reinstall the driver. Besides driver is most likely installed because I can see the wifi in Network Connections.

Answer (score 1):

This video fix that

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVm6GBw-paM

In one of the 5 things he say to try he told me to go to

```
services.msc
```

There is a service called **WLAN Autoconfig Services**. I set it to auto. It's manual.

After I set to auto it's working.

What turned it off? I have little idea.

It seems that when I reset network that setting is turned off.

I noticed that WIFI shows up in Network Configuration. That means driver and the hardware can't possibly be the problem.

The computer knows that I have a WIFI hardware. However, something else that should have transfer that info into WIFI connection in  Network & Internet Settings isn't working.

And that something must be some service.

So yap

Answer (score -1):

Try some of these steps:

Try going into Device Manager finding your WiFi adapter in Network Adapters, disable it then re-enable it.

If that doesn't work, trying updating/roll-back if you can.

Restart if you haven't already tried.

You could uninstall the driver and then restart your computer which *should* reinstall the driver, but it may cause a lot of issues if you can't! If you want to try this I'd recommend finding a way to get the driver onto a USB stick then attempting it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).